# Is Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Program (QCQP) in NP?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, np-complete, qcqp

The general version of **QCQP** is **NP**-hard, but is it also **NP**-complete? That means, is there a non-deterministic algorithm, which solves **QCQP** in polynomial time complexity?

If the general version of **QCQP** is not in **NP**, are there restricted versions such that the problem is in **NP**?